# Table row click using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
$("table tr:eq(0) td:first-child").click();
```

It works fine. What im trying to do is to change the 0 with a value of a variable. Like this:

```
var data = 6;  

$("table tr:eq(data) td:first-child").click();
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

If I write 6 or any number instead 0 it works but not with variable value. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate strings with [**`+`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) operator:

```
$('table tr:eq(' + data + ') td:first-child').click();
```

Comment: Works. Tnx. I have tried this without + op. Tnx again.